# GitHub Group Quest for students - asking for advice

Tags: github

I'm looking for an advice.

I'm organising a small tech event to familiarize university 1st and 2nd years with Github's basics and its collaborative features. I wanted to come up with a simple way 25-30ish students could work on their skills with a simple yet demonstrative task. So this is what I came up with:

They will have to "work" together to fill a progress bar with a certain number of pull requests and reveal a Kahoot game ID. Then they'll be able to win some swag.

Maybe any other suggestions or tips how I could achieve this? Can I automatically track PR numbers or do I have to manually check it after some periods of time? Maybe I could have them each solve a small puzzle and each time reveal the ID number digit?

Thanks

They all know web dev basics but the tasks should still be simple to work with.